# cpprest/pplx : call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of '_ResultHolder<SomeObj>'

Tags: c++, rest, lambda, clang++, casablanca

I am currently using the cpprest API found at https://casablanca.codeplex.com/ for a simple RESTful API project.

This popular library uses Microsoft's PPLX framework to facilitate the async tasks.

I am currently encountering an issue in which code does not compile when a function returns an object of type `pplx::task<SomeObj>` and `SomeObj` has no default constructor.  My understanding is that this code should be a valid as no default objects should be created.

Is there an error in my code or is this a bug?

Example Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <cpprest/http_client.h>

class SomeSubObj {
public:
    int a,b,c;
    SomeSubObj(int a, int b, int c): a(a), b(b), c(c){}
};

class SomeObj {
public:
    std::vector<SomeSubObj> subObjs;
    SomeObj(std::string json){
        // Populate from JSON...
        subObjs.push_back(SomeSubObj(1,1,1));
        subObjs.push_back(SomeSubObj(2,2,2));
        subObjs.push_back(SomeSubObj(3,3,3));
    }
};

pplx::task<SomeObj> doSomething(){
    return pplx::task<std::string>([]() {
        // Make a call out and get some json...
        return std::string("{...}");
    }).then([](std::string x) {
        // Return a transformed object
        return SomeObj("...");
    });
}

int main()
{
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently receiving the following output:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Iboost_thread-mt -Iboost_atomic -Iboost_system -Icpprest -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Bug.d" -MT"src/Bug.d" -o "src/Bug.o" "../src/Bug.cpp"
In file included from ../src/Bug.cpp:4:
In file included from /usr/local/include/cpprest/http_client.h:44:
/usr/local/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h:2404:9: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of '_ResultHolder<SomeObj>'
        _Task_impl(_CancellationTokenState * _Ct, scheduler_ptr _Scheduler_arg)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2096:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj>::_Task_impl' requested here
              __second_(_VSTD::forward<_Args2>(get<_I2>(__second_args))...)
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2359:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<std::__1::allocator<pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj> >, pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj>, 1>::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<std::__1::allocator<pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj> > &, pplx::details::_CancellationTokenState *&, pplx::scheduler_ptr &, 0, 0, 1>' requested here
            : base(__pc, _VSTD::move(__first_args), _VSTD::move(__second_args),
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3697:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair<std::__1::allocator<pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj> >, pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj> >::__compressed_pair<std::__1::allocator<pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj> > &, pplx::details::_CancellationTokenState *&, pplx::scheduler_ptr &>' requested here
            :  __data_(piecewise_construct, _VSTD::forward_as_tuple(__a),
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4271:26: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj>, std::__1::allocator<pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj> > >::__shared_ptr_emplace<pplx::details::_CancellationTokenState *&, pplx::scheduler_ptr &>' requested here
    ::new(__hold2.get()) _CntrlBlk(__a2, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4630:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::shared_ptr<pplx::details::_Task_impl<SomeObj> >::make_shared<pplx::details::_CancellationTokenState *&, pplx::scheduler_ptr &>' requested here
    return shared_ptr<_Tp>::make_shared(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                            ^
/usr/local/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h:1429:103: note: (skipping 1 context in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
        static _Type _Make(_CancellationTokenState * _Ct, scheduler_ptr _Scheduler_arg) { return std::make_shared<_Task_impl<_ReturnType>>(_Ct, _Scheduler_arg); }
                                                                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h:3623:52: note: in instantiation of member function 'pplx::details::_Task_ptr<SomeObj>::_Make' requested here
        _M_Impl = details::_Task_ptr<_ReturnType>::_Make(_Ct, _Scheduler);
                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h:4138:27: note: in instantiation of member function 'pplx::task<SomeObj>::_CreateImpl' requested here
        _ContinuationTask._CreateImpl(_PTokenState, _Scheduler);
                          ^
/usr/local/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h:4101:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pplx::task<std::__1::basic_string<char> >::_ThenImpl<std::__1::basic_string<char>, <lambda at ../src/Bug.cpp:27:10> >' requested here
        return _ThenImpl<_InternalReturnType, _Function>(_Func, _PTokenState, _TaskOptions.get_continuation_context(), _Scheduler, _CreationStack);
               ^
/usr/local/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h:3424:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pplx::task<std::__1::basic_string<char> >::_ThenImpl<std::__1::basic_string<char>, <lambda at ../src/Bug.cpp:27:10> >' requested here
        return _ThenImpl<_ReturnType, _Function>(_Func, _TaskOptions);
               ^
../src/Bug.cpp:27:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pplx::task<std::__1::basic_string<char> >::then<<lambda at ../src/Bug.cpp:27:10> >' requested here
        }).then([](std::string x) {
           ^
/usr/local/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h:844:15: note: default constructor of '_ResultHolder<SomeObj>' is implicitly deleted because field '_Result' has no default constructor
        _Type _Result;
              ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/Bug.o] Error 1
```